# The Toast msg does't show

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I made a button in a 1st page to link to 2nd page, this 2nd page have (A, G, S, J, R) on each line and there should be a `Toast` message (Sorted alphabetically inside) in the same 2nd page, the problem is, it doesnt show that `Toast` message. I just dont know what xml shall I type it

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sorted alphabetically inside", 10000).show();
```

And here is the picture: http://oi61.tinypic.com/mwr1ox.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Try putting:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Sorted alphabetically inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

or:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Sorted alphabetically inside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

These are only options provided. Value for Toast.LENGTH_LONG is 1, and for Toast.LENGTH_SHORT is 0. There si no option for 1000.

Comment: I change it, but still, I don't know how to show it, I know how to put a button for it to show but I don't want that!

Answer (score 1):

Use setDuration(int) to set time limit or Toast.LENGTH_LONG or Toast.LENGTH_SHORT . http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#setDuration(int)